# Doxygen: how to include a markdown page to document a group

Tags: doxygen

I have a rather complex project and I want to document it using doxygen.

I have no problem documenting the code and I also managed to have a nice front-page using a custom `README.md` file coupled with "`USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md`" directive in Doxyfile.

I defined several groups (`@defgroup`) which show up as "Modules" in my documentation.

I would like to add a "main page" to each of the group giving general information, beside the customary function/variable/type documentation.

I tried adding custom `MODULENAME.md` files coupled with matching `@includedoc MODULENAME.md` entries in group definition, it seem to work (I see several lines like: "`Generating docs for page md_mcu_noitr_coro_README...`"), but I cannot find if and where the page is linked (I expected to see it in the "Detailed Description" for the module, as it happens if I put some documentation inline where I put the "`@includedoc`" directive.

a snippet of one of my modules is:

```
/**
 * @file coro.h
 * @brief definition of coroutine implementing functions.
 *
 * @date: Feb 8, 2018
 * @author: myself
 *
 * @defgroup coro "Coroutine implementation in plain 'C'."
 *
 * @includedoc mcu_noitr/coro/README.md
 * @{
 *
 */
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Note:* it is also a bit surprising I need to put the whole path from where my `Doxyfile` is, otherwise doxygen won't find it even if it's right beside the file containing the `@includedoc` command.

Comment: First about the Note. That you need the relative path from where the Doxyfile is / or better said from where doxygen is started is not surprising as it is possible that there are multiple `README.md` files and doxygen should make a guess at that moment.

Comment: Why do you want to do it through a separate file. can't you include the markdown code straight away at the defgroup command?

Comment: @albert: I wanted to add a separate file because it is a substantial piece of writing and it would push "real code" several hundred lines down; other reason is using a real Markdown editor would ease writing, instead of being inside a multiline "C" comment. About the note: I would expect the normal "#include" behavior: compute path relative to including file; Doxygen would have all data to guess right.

Comment: Reasoning is quite valid regarding place and editing. Regarding the 'Note' please submit an issue in the doxygen bug traces (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new). Forgot in the previous comments: which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Just did a small test, looks like not to work, as far as I know this is due to the moment of the markdown parsing. Probably the included documentation has to be 'markdown preprocessed. Probably best to submit an issue  in the doxygen bug traces (github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new) including a, small, self contained example (source+config file in a tar or zip) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: For the 'path' problem a issue has been opened: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6478

Comment: @albert: Yup! I know: I opened issue 6478. That is my "official self" ;)    I will try to add another issue (with a suitable test case) for the main (\includedoc) problem. Thanks, for now.

Comment: I assumed so, but I wanted to have the cross references present so other people can see the discussions as well.

Answer (score 3):

I also came across the problem that included files with Markdown formatted text via `\includedoc` or `\include{doc}` does not result in correctly interpreted Markdown. Note that I included Markdown files from *other* Markdown files. My work-around was to use the C pre-processor (cpp) - which is widely available - on Markdown files and use it's `#include` directive. You could of course use a true general text processor such as [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) as suggested in the cpp man page. Set `FILTER_PATTERNS` in Doxyfile as:

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = *.md="cpp -P -traditional-cpp"
```

You'll need the `-P` option to avoid it outputting line markers, which confuses Doxygen. `-traditional-cpp` was needed to avoid cpp eating white space that is important for the correct interpretation of Markdown. Don't use single quotes as this results in an error when Doxygen calls `cpp` via `sh`.

Then in my Markdown main page:

```
Main Page {#mainpage}
==========

Blah blah blah.

#include "other.md"
```

Using `FILTER_PATTERNS` instead of `INPUT_FILTER` avoids the problem about not being allowed to add or remove lines.

I have my markdown files in the same directory, I would guess that if they are located in different places you could tell cpp about it via `-I`, which would address your expectations about include paths on the [issue](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6478) you filed.

Comment: I cannot make this work. The .md file won't display anything when I use `FILTER_PATTERNS = *.md="cpp -P -traditional-cpp"` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment doxygen does not consider the fact that commands like `\includedoc` can contain markdown code. At the moment the only possibility would be to write a filter, see configuration parateter `INPUT_FILTER` in the doxygen configuration file, (not tested!) to replace the \includedoc` with the code of that file.

Comment: I will explore, but first perusal does not look good: "Note that the filter must not add or remove lines; it is applied before the code is scanned, but not when the output code is generated. If lines are added or removed, the anchors will not be placed correctly."

Comment: I agree that the `INPUT_FILTER` probably won't work because of the arguments mentioned by you, therefore the issue is probably the only way to go ( :-( )

Comment: Uhm... I see a VERY long list of backlog patches (including one from yourself dated Feb 23, 2014!). How responsive is, in your opinion, doxygen core group?

Comment: Depends on the patch there is a backlog, but I've recently added a considerable number of proposed patches as you can see. There are currently 78 patches in the master that were not in the latest release and there are also some fixes directly from Dimitri. A proposed patch doesn't always make it into the release as it e.g. contradicts the doxygen philosophy or breaks some other code.

Comment: The doxygen core group is not that big (Dimitri) and there are also other tasks to be done besides the normal work (it is all voluntarily!). Some other tasks this year were moving from bugzilla to github issue tracker, moving the file hosting / email address from stack.nl to  sourceforge / gmail, ...